# Regex pattern for a number inside square bracket

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to replace strings which start with a number inside a square bracket with a word.

```
[1]FirstWord!FF  >> FirstReplace!!FF
[2]SecondWord!FF  >> SecondReplace!!FF
```

This code only works if there is no `[number]` at the beginning.

```
'test!FF' %>% str_replace_all("test(['\"])?!","replace!")
```

But how can I update the pattern if I have something like below:

```
'[1]test!FF' %>% str_replace_all("[1]test(['\"])?!","replace!")
```

Comment: Try `'[1]test!FF' |>  stringr::str_replace_all("\\[1\\]test(['\"])?!","replace!")`, i.e. you have to escape `[` and `]`.

Comment: @stefan how can I also escape the number between the brackets since I don't now the number. \\[1\\]

Comment: Try `\\[\\d\\]` to match any digit inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```r
'[1]test!FF' %>% str_replace_all("\\[\\d+]test['\"]?!", "replace!")
## => [1] "replace!FF"
```

**Note**: If the `[number]` part is optional, wrap it with an optional non-capturing group: `"(?:\\[\\d+])?test['\"]?!"`.

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char
- `test` - a `test` word
- `['\"]?` - an optional `"` or `'`
- `!` - a `!` char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I noticed the number can be different sometimes for the same title. How I can modify it to have a pattern like  \[1\](['"])?Test(['"])?! instead of using \d+

Comment: @ZachFara If the number is hardcoded, there is no problem, just replace `\d+` with this number. `"\\[1]test['\"]?!"`

Comment: Thanks, how I can get a pattern like this \[1\](['"])? , sorry I am really new to Regex and trying a find a way to figure things out.

Comment: @ZachFara Just type it by hand, what is the problem? See [the R demo](https://ideone.com/ce6BOm).

Comment: I am using R, It does not work when I put it in ' ', It seems  I need to add parenthesis around it  or \\ before the brackets to make it work but can't figure it out.

Comment: @ZachFara Please provide a test case, like I have just done at https://ideone.com/ce6BOm.

Comment: I got this to work '\\[1\\]([\'"])' Thank you

Comment: @ZachFara Note that there is no need to escape the `]` char outside of a character class.